# How can I ignore window.onpopstate on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm playing with `window.onpopstate`, and there is a thing that annoys me:

> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load.
> Chrome and Safari always emit a popstate event on page load, but
> Firefox doesn't.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate)

I tested it, and yeah, in Chrome and Safari 5.1+ the popstate event is fired on page load, but not in Firefox or IE10.

The problem is, that I want to listen only to `popstate` events where user clicked the *back* or *forward* button (or the history was changed via javascript), but don't want to do anything on pageload.

In other words, I want to differentiate the `popstate` event from *page load* from the other `popstate` events.

This is what I tried so far (I'm using jQuery):

```
$(function() {
  console.log('document ready');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      // Do something here
    }, 10);
});
```

Basically I'm try to bind my `listener` function to `popstate` late enough to be not bound on page load, only later.

This seems to work; however, I don't like this solution. How can I be sure that the *timeout* chosen for setTimeout is big enough, but not too big (because I don't want it to wait too much).

I hope for a smarter solution!

Comment: This bug seems to have been fixed on Chrome already.

Comment: Please update your question, it happens only with safari as of today. Chrome seems to have fixed this.

Comment: This misfired `popstate` happens just after the `onload` processing which means 1ms is **always enough** to postpone the `popstate` registration (because JS has no multi-threading and process the postponed functions in the order they were registered).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check for boolean truth of `event.state` in `popstate` event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    if (event.state) {
        alert('!');
    }
}, false);
```

To ensure this will work, **always** specify a non-`null` state argument when calling `history.pushState()` or `history.replaceState()`. Also, consider using a wrapper library like [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) that provides consistent behavior across browsers.

Comment: Yes, the event.state is empty on pageload, but can also be empty if pushState is called without state defined, like: `history.pushState(null, null, url)`;

Comment: So always define a state or write a wrapper class (or use an [existing one](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)) that will make such things implicitly. Native implementations of HTML5 History API are inconsistent, so we are forced to have some tradeoff anyway.

Comment: Yes, I will use a wrapper class, and never use `null` for state when calling `pushState` or `replaceState`. Please update your answer with your last comment, so I can accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To clarify: make sure to call `history.pushState(state, null, url)`, do not use null on the first parameter. When Safari calls `popstate` on page load, the `event.state` will be nil. This is how to differentiate between initial page load vs explicit pushState call

Comment: if i do `pushState` in **page2** then while fire `popstate` the `event.state` will be **null**. if i do `pushState` 2 times i have a valid `event.state` while comeback, but user should press back button 3 times to see **page1**

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and i had to validate to make sure if page was loaded completely.

I used something like this :

```
var page_loaded = false;    
window.onpopstate = function(event){
    if(!page_loaded){
       page_loaded = true;
       return false;
     }
    //Continue With Your Code
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking about a solution like this. The problem is, that window load happens before the first onpopstate, so `page_loaded` will be always true. (JSBin: http://jsbin.com/awidol/1/edit)

Comment: @TamasPap than a solution could be refusing to execute the code on first time, change page_load to true and than continue with the code.

Comment: Yeah, but then in Fireworks and IE10 the first onpopstate will not happen.

Comment: @TamasPap Than try to detect the browser and fill the if condition to get executed only on browsers which do that.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, this is what I've done, its not a clear fix, however it works 99% of the time:
`var JUST_LOADED = true;
setTimeout(function(){JUST_LOADED=false},399);`

Answer (score 5):

To react on `popstate` event, you need to push some state onto the session history.

For example add this line to the document ready section:

```
history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
```

Not ideal, but it works in Chrome, Firefox and other browsers as well.

Then the event is fired correctly when user clicks on *Back* or *Forward* button, also when `history.back()`, `history.forward()`, `history.go()` methods are called manually. Each time when `popstate` has been invoked, you have to push another state again to make it working.

See also:

- [Single-Page Apps and HTML5 pushState](http://zinoui.com/blog/single-page-apps-html5-pushstate)
- [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25806608/55075)

Answer (score 2):

It seems none of the browsers are emitting the event on page load any more as of today:

> Browsers used to handle the popstate event differently on page load, but now they behave the same. Firefox never emitted a popstate event on page load. Chrome did until version 34, while Safari did until version 10.0.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PopStateEvent