# popstate fire on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(){
    window.history.go(-1);
});
```

I have a page use popstate when user click back button

but in some browser, popstate fire on page load instead back button click.

it happen in Safari and touch device.

Comment: I think this will work for you. Click on [popstate-fire-on-page-load-issue][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896434/window-onpopstate-on-page-load

Answer (score 1):

The easiest hack/solution, is to add the popstate listener right after the initial page load, in a setTimeout.

```
 setTimeout( function() {
    window.addEventListener( 'popstate', myPopStateHandler, false );
  }, 500 );
```

I’m weary of throwing a setTimeout in for a resolution, always seems like a kludge. But for now, hey it works.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a flag to detect page load fixed this for me.

Edit: added Safari browser detection, otherwise first click of back button won't trigger popstate event in Firefox or Chrome.

```
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent),
    firstLoad = true;
$(window).on('popstate', function(){
    if (isSafari && firstLoad) {
        firstLoad = false;
        return;
    } else {
        // run your popstate code
    }
});
```