# Detecting URL Change in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not a hash change but a URL change. I know that with hashes you can use the jquery plugin like so

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
 // Your Code goes here
});
```

but i've yet to see how to detect a url change that doesn't involve a hash.

ex.

> http://www.google.com -> http://www.google.com/woot

I want to be able to detect a certain URL so i can run a function that will display a button on that page.

Comment: From what I understand, the only way to do this is via polling the `window.location.href` property.

Comment: Give `window.onpopstate` a try. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15897177/575199

Comment: Are you using History API? If not, changing the url will load a new page and unload the old one.

Comment: @Oriol can you cite an example?